# webhook to AWS Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, webhooks

I am creating the AWS Lambda Function, Where the values will be sent in the post method on the Webhook Url from the chat bot. Can anyone suggest me to create the webhook from WP site to the AWS Lambda so that i can able to make it in working condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the AWS lambda on triggers like SQS queue trigger, s3 trigger, etc. So You can do one thing once your post method calls upload a JSON file to S3 and apply trigger that whenever any file uploaded to your S3 bucket trigger the AWS lambda in this way it will work. You can even define some URL with Route 53 and trigger lambda when that URL hits.